# Enforce return value type for GraphQL resolvers in NestJS

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Is there a way to enforce the return value of a `@Query` function inside resolvers? Given the code below:

```
@Resolver(() => Project)
export class ProjectResolver {
  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) {}

  @Query(() => [ProjectFull])
  async projects() {
    // return anything
  }
}
```

`projects` method can return anything w/o Typescript complaining. We could annotate the method with a return type (even enforce this annotation using `eslint`), but it won't be *attached* to the return type of a query.

Comment: There is an eslint plugin eslint-plugin-nestjs-graphql to enforce correct typing.